# Sizing pipes for a filter system with two pumps and one inlet and outlet, bernoulli and venturi?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, water, flow

I need help with a concrete problem that needs solving through good application of physics principles. Here's the problem:

I would like to build a filtering system for my bestway pool, the pool has only one inlet and one outlet for filtering water, diameter of each 32 mm.

I also have a system that can heat the water by passing the filtered water through some 1/2 inch pipes (that are buried under concrete, so I can't replace them) to a heat exchanger to the heat pump.

And I have a 10 M3/h filtering pump. My problem is that the pipes to the heating are too small for the 10M3/h pump, this causes a pressure build up in the sand filter, which is plastic, breaking it rather quickly.

I would like to modify the system, so that the 10m3/h pump is only used for actual filtering, while the heating is done using a smaller pump (2.5 m3/h). The pool still has only one intake and one outtake for water, so I will need at some point to have some sort of T split. to split the two flows, and rejoin them after heating/filtering. like shown here: [image: pumps schema]

Because the two pumps are very different in their hydraulic characteristics, I'm worried that I won't be able to run both pumps at the same time, i.e. the powerful one will make the small one useless.

I'm looking for a solution to this:

Venturi said that if I have a pipe, and reduce it's diameter in the shrinkage I'll get lower pressure. I imagine the opposite will be true too: if I enlarge the pipe, I'll get a higher pressure.

[image: venturi with reverse]

So if

- pressure at A = pressure at B
- pipe diameter at A = diameter at B
- main pipe diameter at C < diameter at A
- main pipe diameter at D > pipe diameter at B

then

- pressure at C < pressure at A
- pressure at D > pressure at B
- pressure at C < pressure at D

I could then join these two pieces together as in the figure:

[image: lateral flow]

because there's a higher pressure at B (pipe C)  than there's at F (pipe D), then there must be a flow in the lateral pipe C-D. even when there's no pump in this pipe, but only one located at E.

now, I'm not too sure there can be real flow without a pump on C-D but at least I hope I might be able to have a smaller pump on C-D running the water heating system.

I'm planning to 3d print the parts for this, so I have the chance to calibrate the sizes of all the pipes.

If this principle is sound, how would I calculate the diameters of the pipes and how would I shape the T junctions to make it work?

I got this idea from this: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4920000

Comment: A different idea: install a bypass line on the pump discharge around the heat exchanger.  Put a pressure gauge in the pump outlet line and a valve in the bypass line.  When the system is running, adjust the valve in the bypass line to keep the heat exchanger inlet pressure within desirable limits.

Comment: What is the purpose of your modified system? Since you have a filter and heating system we can suggest that you try to produce clean and warm water. From your sketch it follows that clean cold water from one tube and warm not clean water from another tube mixed up in one tube.  Therefore you have not clean and not warm water in the pool.

Comment: @DavidWhite that can be also an idea. and it would use a single pump. But the current system has already broken two filter tanks (HDPE didn't stand the pressure) I'm worried that misusing it could break one more of the tanks

Comment: @AlexTrounev well the water would pass through one of the pipes, and it's not that the filter chills it. also I didn't mention that the smaller pump is actually also a filter (a less performing one). I'm just looking for a way to get the two circuits to get a flow of water,  work without the system breaking, and using the two inlets available on the poll, that's all I have.

Comment: @DonGiulio, I'm basing my recommendation on 21 years of industrial experience in the field of chemical engineering.  In my opinion, my suggestion has a better chance of working than trying to place two different sized pumps in parallel.

Comment: @DavidWhite ok, I'll try your idea then, currently it's sort of set the way you propose, with a bypass before the actual heat exchanger, but I guess the problem is that the bypass is done with 1" pipes, so the flow is already reduced at that point, like in the photo: https://imgur.com/WvNrBv6 . in this setup the tank visibly (not much in the video) expands when the pump is on: https://imgur.com/a/9ZnIb6S

Comment: @DonGiulio, if you have the option, a full sized bypass line with a valve will give you the opportunity to adjust your system through a broad range of flows (and pressures).  If that still doesn't provide pressure protection for the sand filter, you should put a valve just upstream of that filter (if you can) and pinch down on the valve to reduce the pressure going to it.  Just make sure that you maintain adequate flow through your pump.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWhite I changed the way you said, the tank doesn't inflate any more, and now there's a lot more flow going back to the pool (as in more water being filtered), it costed me a fortune, because all the pipes on the main line need to be 2" (not to reduce the flow at any point except in the ball valve) while the flow is reduced straight away to 1" in the secondary flow. here's the final result: https://imgur.com/7PJ5NI8

Comment: @DonGiulio, I'm glad I could help.  I recommended the most practical and easiest fix I could think of in the hope that you would have a solution that you wouldn't have to "fight" and redesign several times.